# How to prevent dtype change when writing and loading csvs of numerical strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, types

I am trying to write numerical strings to a csv and reading it back in as a dataframe later on. However pandas automatically converts my strings on reading from `object` type to `int64` type.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1':['00123','00125']}) 
print(df['col1'].dtype) 
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
new_df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv') 
print(new_df['col1'].dtype)

object #value of first print
int64 #value of second print
```

How do I, either preserve the dtype on write or prevent the change on read?

EDIT: I noticed that if I use `astype('|S')` on df new_df will now be an object type. even though df.dtype does not change. This does not seem intuitive to me. If anyone can explain this to me I would appreciate it.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1':['00123','00125']}) 
df['col1']=df['col1'].astype('|S')  
print(df['col1'].dtype) 
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False) 
new_df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv') 
print(new_df['col1'].dtype)

object #value of first print
object #value of second print
```

Comment: If you only read/write by python, you may want some libraries that handle binary format, e.g. `joblib` works pretty well with `pandas` DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend write those type df to excel

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx',index=False)
```

Or pass the columns type while you reading the file

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv',dtype = {'col1': object})
Out[346]: 
    col1
0  00123
1  00125
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I would like to do the second suggestion but I don't think I would have the dtype info before hand.